# "Object required" error though i've set all variables in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I've set all variables but I still keep getting the error "object required" at

```
For Each cll In OHLC
```

This is my code:

```
Sub hellohello()

Dim i As Integer
Dim OHLC, cll As Range
Dim stoplossb, entrypriceb As Variant

stoplossb = 1
entrypriceb = 1
i = 1


For i = 63 To 166

    If Range("M" & i).Value = "buy" Then
        stoplossb = Range("X" & i)
        entrypriceb = Range("w" & i)
        Set OHLC = Range("B" & i & ":" & "E10000")
       ' Set twndlow = Range("K" & i & ":" & "K10000")
    End If

    For Each cll In OHLC

        If cll.Value < stoplossb Then
            Range("Y" & cll.Row) = cll.Value
            Exit For
        End If

    Next cll
Next i

End Sub
```

What's my error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set OHLC to an empty Range in an else statement before end if.

Or put the for inside the if block

```
Sub hellohello()

Dim i As Integer
Dim OHLC, cll As Range
Dim stoplossb, entrypriceb As Variant

stoplossb = 1
entrypriceb = 1
i = 1


For i = 63 To 166

    If Range("M" & i).Value = "buy" Then
        stoplossb = Range("X" & i)
        entrypriceb = Range("w" & i)
        Set OHLC = Range("B" & i & ":" & "E10000")
       ' Set twndlow = Range("K" & i & ":" & "K10000")

        For Each cll In OHLC

            If cll.Value < stoplossb Then
                Range("Y" & cll.Row) = cll.Value
                Exit For
            End If

        Next cll

    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Well my friend I don't think you'll find help if you keep putting negative points to our answers. I fact your question denotes no investigation at all only paste the code and ask for help.

Comment: I ran the fix I proposed and the error stop happening. What is not working with our answers?

Comment: Thanks everyone and Carlos, now it works. I think there was probably another error in my code previously that interrupted it.

Comment: Good to know it finally worked. Please if you can drop the negative points because everyone gave you a good answer

Comment: Ok, but my reputation is lower than 15 so I can't directly drop it, neither do I know if the negative point was entered by me in the first place. So sorry! and Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting an error is because your IF statement is not true, therefore you never get to the line that sets OHLC as a range.  Since the range is never set the range is equal to nothing.

Comment: Yes i know what he meant, and i tried both methods, setting an else OHLC to an empty range, but it didn't work

Comment: I didn't say to set it to empty, that was someone else's comment.  You already have an empty range because you never get to define OHLC, therefore you are trying to select cells in a range that is empty.  Take the `End If` line that is below the grayed out line and move it after the line `Next cll` and your error will go away.  You asked why you had the error, not for a full rewrite.  Like Carlos said about the rating...

Comment: yes i know what you're saying, and im telling you i just tried it, and the error is still there.

Answer (score 0):

what Carlos is saying is that you have an outer loop that runs from 63 to 166, inside that loop you have an IF statement whereby you decide whether or not to set OHLC but then you have an inner loop which runs regardless of whether or not OHLC was set in the IF statement.. I think you need to move the End If down to just after next cll that way your inner FOR loop will only run when OHLC is set

Comment: Hi, i have tried this method and it still shows the same error! :(

Comment: like carlos said, hitting negative 1 doesn't inspire people to help you

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim OHLC As Range, cll As Range
```